# How can I implement text sharing from other Android apps to my Flutter note app?

Tags: android, flutter

I'm developing a note-taking app in Flutter and I want to enable users to share text from other Android apps directly to my note app. For instance, if a user finds some interesting text in another app, they should be able to share it to my app as a note.

I've seen similar functionality in various apps, where you can select text, hit the share button, and then choose the note app as an option to share the text with.

Could someone guide me on how to implement this feature using Flutter? Specifically, how can I set up the Android intent filters, handle the shared data, and process it within my Flutter app?

Any code examples, package recommendations, or step-by-step instructions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the receive_sharing_intent package. It has a pretty detailed example for how to use it.

https://pub.dev/packages/receive_sharing_intent

Comment: I have tried this package, did not work for me. Have you any github demostrations about this problem?